# Failed to launch iOS Simulator: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, android-studio, ios-simulator

Flutter doctor -v(same result with and without ios simulator running)

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/faizan/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (8 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/faizan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/faizan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    ✗ Xcode 10.1.0 out of date (12.0.1 is recommended).
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.25.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

No devices in bottom tab of vscode even i started the ios simulator. Same happens with android studio

[image]

I tried both 12.0.1 xcode and 10.1 with and without command line tools

Answer (score 22):

Go to your system activity monitor, search for `simulator`, double click on it, then quit ==> then fore quit.

It should work afterwards. Don't know why it happens, but it's not the first time, happens on and off.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  In my case I have a script running that calls `xcrun simctl create` and if the script exits before deleting this simulator instance, the process hangs.